# Проблема с запуском приложения

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения

При запуске происходит остановка приложения в 1 строке метода setLevel(), следующая ошибка в методе setTextOfAnswer(). Построение не вызывает.

Помогите, пожалуйста, их решить!!!

```
package com.appsforteaching.multitable;

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private int levelIndex = 0;
private static final int MAX_LEVEL_INDEX = 8;
private int mistakeIndex = 0;
private int rightAnswerIndex = 0;

private String tasks2[] = new String[] {"2 * 1 =", "2 * 2 =", "2 * 3 =", "2 * 4 =", "2 * 5 =", "2 * 6 =", "2 * 7 =", "2 * 8 =", "2 * 9 ="};
private String tasks3[] = new String[] {"3 * 1 =", "3 * 2 =", "3 * 3 =", "3 * 4 =", "3 * 5 =", "3 * 6 =", "3 * 7 =", "3 * 8 =", "3 * 9 ="};
private String tasks4[] = new String[] {"4 * 1 =", "4 * 2 =", "4 * 3 =", "4 * 4 =", "4 * 5 =", "4 * 6 =", "4 * 7 =", "4 * 8 =", "4 * 9 ="};
private String tasks5[] = new String[] {"5 * 1 =", "5 * 2 =", "5 * 3 =", "5 * 4 =", "5 * 5 =", "5 * 6 =", "5 * 7 =", "5 * 8 =", "5 * 9 ="};
private String tasks6[] = new String[] {"6 * 1 =", "6 * 2 =", "6 * 3 =", "6 * 4 =", "6 * 5 =", "6 * 6 =", "6 * 7 =", "6 * 8 =", "6 * 9 ="};
private String tasks7[] = new String[] {"7 * 1 =", "7 * 2 =", "7 * 3 =", "7 * 4 =", "7 * 5 =", "7 * 6 =", "7 * 7 =", "7 * 8 =", "7 * 9 ="};
private String tasks8[] = new String[] {"8 * 1 =", "8 * 2 =", "8 * 3 =", "8 * 4 =", "8 * 5 =", "8 * 6 =", "8 * 7 =", "8 * 8 =", "8 * 9 ="};
private String tasks9[] = new String[] {"9 * 1 =", "9 * 2 =", "9 * 3 =", "9 * 4 =", "9 * 5 =", "9 * 6 =", "9 * 7 =", "9 * 8 =", "9 * 9 ="};
private String tasks[][] = {tasks2, tasks3, tasks4, tasks5, tasks6, tasks7, tasks8, tasks9};

private int answerVariants2[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18};
private int answerVariants3[] = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27};
private int answerVariants4[] = {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36};
private int answerVariants5[] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45};
private int answerVariants6[] = {6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54};
private int answerVariants7[] = {7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63};
private int answerVariants8[] = {8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72};
private int answerVariants9[] = {9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81};
private int allAnswerVariants[][] = {answerVariants2, answerVariants3, answerVariants4, answerVariants5, answerVariants6, answerVariants7, answerVariants8, answerVariants9};


private Button levelButton2;
private Button levelButton3;
private Button levelButton4;
private Button levelButton5;
private Button levelButton6;
private Button levelButton7;
private Button levelButton8;
private Button levelButton9;
private Button finalLevelButton;
private Button allLevelButtons [] = {levelButton2, levelButton3, levelButton4, levelButton5, levelButton6, levelButton7, levelButton8, levelButton9, finalLevelButton};

private Button answerButton1;
private Button answerButton2;
private Button answerButton3;
private Button answerButton4;
private Button answerButton5;
private Button answerButton6;
private Button answerButton7;
private Button answerButton8;
private Button answerButton9;
private Button allAnswerButtons[] = {answerButton1, answerButton2, answerButton3, answerButton4, answerButton5, answerButton6, answerButton7, answerButton8, answerButton9};

private Button nextButton;
private ImageView imageView;
private TextView taskTextView;

private int imageArray[] = {R.drawable.multi_table_01, R.drawable.multi_table_02, R.drawable.multi_table_03,
        R.drawable.multi_table_04, R.drawable.multi_table_05, R.drawable.multi_table_06, R.drawable.multi_table_07,
        R.drawable.multi_table_08, R.drawable.multi_table_09, R.drawable.multi_table_10, R.drawable.multi_table_11,
        R.drawable.multi_table_12, R.drawable.multi_table_13, R.drawable.multi_table_14, R.drawable.multi_table_15,
        R.drawable.multi_table_16, R.drawable.multi_table_17, R.drawable.multi_table_18, R.drawable.multi_table_19,
        R.drawable.multi_table_20, R.drawable.multi_table_21, R.drawable.multi_table_22, R.drawable.multi_table_23,
        R.drawable.multi_table_24, R.drawable.multi_table_25, R.drawable.multi_table_26, R.drawable.multi_table_27,
        R.drawable.multi_table_28, R.drawable.multi_table_29, R.drawable.multi_table_30, R.drawable.multi_table_31,
        R.drawable.multi_table_32, R.drawable.multi_table_33, R.drawable.multi_table_34, R.drawable.multi_table_35,
        R.drawable.multi_table_36, R.drawable.multi_table_37, R.drawable.multi_table_38, R.drawable.multi_table_39,
        R.drawable.multi_table_40};


Random random = new Random();


private void setTextOfTask() {

    if (rightAnswerIndex == 9) {

        if (mistakeIndex == 0) {
            taskTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.well_done));
            levelIndex++;
            setLevel();
        }

        else if (mistakeIndex == 1) {
            taskTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.well));
            levelIndex++;
            setLevel();
        }

        else if (mistakeIndex >= 2 && mistakeIndex <= 3) {
            taskTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.not_bad));
            setLevel();
        }

        else {
            taskTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.try_to_do_better));
            setLevel();
        }
    }

    else {

        if (levelIndex >= 0 && levelIndex <= MAX_LEVEL_INDEX) {
            taskTextView.setText(tasks[levelIndex][random.nextInt(10)]);
        } else {
            taskTextView.setText(tasks[random.nextInt(10)][random.nextInt(10)]);
        }
    }
}

private void setTextOfAnswer() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Start of setting texts of answers");
    if (levelIndex <= MAX_LEVEL_INDEX) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){

            allAnswerButtons[random.nextInt(10)].setText(allAnswerVariants[levelIndex][random.nextInt(10)]);
        }
    }

    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            allAnswerButtons[random.nextInt(10)].setText(allAnswerVariants[random.nextInt(10)][random.nextInt(10)]);
        }
    }

}

private void setLevel() {
    allLevelButtons[levelIndex].setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.activeLevel));
    Log.d(TAG, "The color of the level button have been already set");
    imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[random.nextInt(41)]);
    Log.d(TAG, "Image have been already set");
    setTextOfTask();
    Log.d(TAG, "Text of task have been already set");
    setTextOfAnswer();
    Log.d(TAG, "Texts of answers have been already set");
}

private boolean checkAnswer(int numberOfButton) {
    int num = --numberOfButton;
    boolean truth = false;

    if (levelIndex >= 0 && levelIndex <= MAX_LEVEL_INDEX) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                if (taskTextView.getText().toString().equals(tasks[i][j])) {
                    int m = Integer.parseInt(allAnswerButtons[num].getText().toString());
                    if (allAnswerVariants[i][j] == m)
                            /*(Integer.parseInt(allAnswerButtons[num].getText().toString())).equals(allAnswerVariants[i][j])) */{
                        allAnswerButtons[num].setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.positive));
                        truth = true;

                    }
                    else {
                        mistakeIndex++;
                        allAnswerButtons[num].setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.negative));
                        truth = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return truth;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    levelButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level_button_2);
    levelButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level_button_3);
    levelButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level_button_4);
    levelButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level_button_5);
    levelButton6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level_button_6);
    levelButton7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level_button_7);
    levelButton8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level_button_8);
    levelButton9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.level_button_9);
    finalLevelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.final_level_button);

    answerButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_1);
    answerButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_2);
    answerButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_3);
    answerButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_4);
    answerButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_5);
    answerButton6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_6);
    answerButton7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_7);
    answerButton8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_8);
    answerButton9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button_9);

    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    taskTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task_TextView);

    Log.d(TAG, "Level is being set");
    setLevel();
    Log.d(TAG, "Level set");


    levelButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = 0;
            setLevel();
        }
    });

   levelButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = 1;
            setLevel();
        }
    });

   levelButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = 2;
            setLevel();
        }
    });

   levelButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = 3;
            setLevel();
        }
    });

   levelButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = 4;
            setLevel();
        }
    });

   levelButton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = 5;
            setLevel();
        }
    });

   levelButton8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = 6;
            setLevel();
        }
    });

   levelButton9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = 7;
            setLevel();
        }
    });

   finalLevelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex = MAX_LEVEL_INDEX;
            setLevel();
        }
    });


    answerButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(1)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    answerButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(2)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    answerButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(3)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    answerButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(4)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    answerButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(5)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    answerButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(6)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    answerButton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(7)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    answerButton8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(8)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    answerButton9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkAnswer(9)) {
                rightAnswerIndex++;
                answerButton9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                setTextOfTask();
            }
        }
    });

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelIndex++;
            setLevel();
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Без логов ошибки помочь сложно. С ними же ответить на вопрос - дело 30с

Comment: В `onCreate` вы инициализируете levelbutton2..9 и answerButton1..9, но при этом массивы `allLevelButton` и `allAnswerButton` по прежнему содержат `null`

Comment: так же массивы `tasks` и `allAnswerVariants` двумерные, а задано только одно "измерение"